# Localisation and configuration in the Sass module system

Tags: css, sass, module, architecture, localization

I've been using [Sass's new module system](https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched) for a while now, and for the most part have grokked how it works. One use case that I can't work out how to translate from the old system to new however is how to produce mostly identical stylesheets with only minor variations and configuration changes—for the purposes of localisation.

(CSS Custom Properties unfortunately aren't really an option for this. That would make this way easier!)

---

In the past, I've achieved this by having an entry file for each locale, with the configuration info for that locale, which could be grabbed by all the following imported files and make whatever locale-specific manipulations it needs to. For example:

`en.scss`

```
$locale: "en";
$rtl: false;
$font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;

@import "shared/code";
```

`ar.scss`

```
$locale: "ar";
$rtl: true;
$font-family: sans-serif;

@import "shared/code";
```

When processed I'd end up with an `en.css` file with only the CSS that English requires and an `ar.css` file with only the CSS that Arabic requires, and all is good.

This is no longer possible in the Sass module system. Because an explicit aim of the module system was to remove global variables and more tightly scope things to individual files, `@import` has been deprecated in favour of `@use` and `@forward`, neither of which allow "children" access to the variables of the "parent" file.

---

My first thought was to lean into the module system and create an importable configuration file for each locale. Doing something like this works:

```
@use "locale/en" as locale;

html {
    font-family: locale.$font-family;
}
```

However, now my locale reference is hardcoded into every file that requires it. `@use` only accepts a string (no variables), so I can't try and be clever with it, and I can't generate CSS for multiple locales without editing several files first. Fail.

My current hack-y solution is to `@use "config";` everywhere, store my locale variables in a bunch of different configuration files, and then change the name of a locale file to "config" when I need to compile for that locale. This is obviously unsustainable and prone to human error a-plenty, so I'd like a second opinion on if there's some other method of doing this that has just completely passed me by, or whether this use case just isn't possible under the new Sass module system anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of `with (...)` [configuration in the module syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#configuration). The importing file is still able to configure variables in the loaded module - that just happens with a more explicit syntax:

```
// en.scss
@use "shared/code" with (
  $locale: "en",
  $rtl: false,
  $font-family: ("Gill Sans", sans-serif),
);
```

and:

```
// ar.scss
@use "shared/code" with (
  $locale: "ar",
  $rtl: true,
  $font-family: sans-serif,
);
```

Comment: Thanks Miriam! A follow-up, if it's not too much trouble: 

My shared code file is currently a big list of `@use` statements that would formerly have been `@import`s, and having to list the same `with` variables for each one is going to get very repetitive. Is there a way to streamline this for nested `@use`s? 

Thanks again!

Comment: I've had a poke at some of your GitHub repos and see how you've achieved similar to this in the Cascading Color System with `@forward`, so feel free to ignore the above. It seems like there's now a need to have a default setting (for example, `$rtl: false !default;`) at the top of every partial that uses it, which makes sense, if is a little inconvenient. Doubly thanks again!

Comment: Hi @querkmachine! Yeah, `@forward with (…)` is a good way to chain configurations so you're only making minor adjustments. (I fixed my accidental `{}` above to the correct `()`). I wouldn't re-declare `$rtl: false !default;` at the top of every file. Again you can look at something like Cascading Colors to see that config variables are defined once, and then that configuration file is: 1) Forwarded first, so config happens right away, and 2) imported in every file that needs access to the configuration. Hope that helps!